# C# Flow Control devCodeCamp task

Tags: c#

I have been stuck on this task all day for foundations of C# for devCodeCamp (new enrollee) I have googled and read until my brain hurts. My problem is I don't know if I have finished the task or if I am missing something.

Here is the code from the very first task that I did:

```
 {
    int hoursWorked = 35;
    double payRate = 7.25;
    double totalPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
    Console.WriteLine(totalPay);
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

End result is 253.75 as expected.

The next part of task is this.
Flow Control Task: Pay Calculator v2

The task for flow control will be another rendition of the pay calculator that you did earlier. However, this version will take into account overtime when calculating total pay.

For this next task, let's start by creating a new class called 'CSharpExercises'. We will use this class for the next couple tasks.

In your new class, create a public member method called 'RunPayCalculator'. Give this method two parameters so that the 'hoursWorked' and 'payRate' can be passed into this method from the outside. This method is where you will write the logic for your pay calculator! Your method should end by returning the calculated 'totalPay'.

As always, test your method by calling it in the Main() method of the Program class! Feel free to pass in any values you like for the two parameters of your method. Be sure to test the method with in both scenarios so that you can see it working for both overtime calculations and non-overtime calculations!

Lastly, don't forget that you can drop a breakpoint now and do a little debugging if you notice an issue!

My code so far:

```
public class CSharpExercises
    {
        // member variables

        // constructor

        // member methods
        public static double RunPayCalculator(int hoursWorked, double payRate)
        {
            double result = hoursWorked * payRate;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if I'm finished with part of the task or if I still need to do more. I know my brain hurts and I am stuck.

Comment: Based on what's written in the task, you're missing logic for overtime calculations

Comment: So do I just come up with some parameters for overtime like multiplying by 1.5 or something?

Comment: Generally, when calculating overtime, there's a cut off number of hours. Time worked up to that time is straight pay. Time worked beyond that is 1.5x. Fir example, let's say the cut off is 40 hrs and the pay rate is $15/hr. If you work 30 or 40 hours, your pay is $450 or $600. But, if you work 50 hours, you get paid $600 for the first 40 hours, but 1.5x (i.e. $22.50/hr) for the remaining hours (10 x $22.5 = $225), so your total pay would be $400+$225

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm definitely gonna have to do some more studying and research to understand this all. I am horrible at math and any relating to math, but I hope I'll catch on to programming soon.